# How to wait for a broadcast to be received?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Hi and thanks for your attention.

I have the following scenario:

- my applications needs to send an SMS to a device;
- it has to wait for another SMS in reply;
- if the response SMS is received within 20 seconds OK;
- if the response SMS is NOT received within 20 seconds (or not received at all) NOT OK;

Now, I know how to send an SMS.

I know that to receive the SMS I have to implement a BroadcastReceiver that listens to `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`.

Now the problem is: how do I measure the time from the moment I send the SMS and the moment I receive the response SMS? And if no SMS response comes?

Comment: fancy posting some code for us to edit to make it work or so that we can give you more detailed advice?

Comment: @apmartin1991 Hi apmartin1991, I haven't implemented this part yet, because I would like to figure this problem out before coding :-)

Comment: Okay, when you send an SMS you should start a timer, which increments every second, (no need for me to give code for a timer, there are millions of examples out there!) when you then receive a text you stop the timer, you then get the number of seconds it took for a text to be received! :) If this is the correct answer, let me know and I will put this in the answer field so you can mark it as correct :)